# Long running operation monitoring using Web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wpf, multithreading, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a long running operation using multi-threading to process some data. I need to provide a User Interface to allow user to start the process and check progress of the long running operation.

It is easy provide progress report with windows based application (WPF) using backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(). However, I have to create web based UI using Angular 2/MVC.

What is the best way to achieve this using Angular 2/MVC/Web Api?

Edit: I do not have a database to store results temporarily.

Thanks.

Comment: Let the user send the request and notify him periodically with SignalR. The alternative approach is to create an endpoint where you can check actual status and ask it periodically to get the status.

Comment: SignalR is a good option. Thanks.

Comment: If I create an endpoint then how can I access the state of the long running operation without storing it in a database?

Comment: store it in memory. Anyway if you have long running tasks you should combine it with Quartz.net library